# form sends values that are not changing anything

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

I have a simple form:

```
<form id="change_id" action="change.php?change=profile"
      method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="change_username" required name="jmeno_new"
           type="text" placeholder="New Username">
</form>
```

Also, I am sending data from my `form` element via AJAX request like so:

```
save_button.addEventListener('click', function ()
{
    var fd = new FormData(change_id);
    XXHR().request(change_id.getAttribute("action"), function(r){
        var obj = JSON.parse(r);
        if (obj.type == 'success')
        {}

        else if (obj.type == 'success_un')
        {
            console.log("YEAH! THAT WORKS.");
        }
    }, function(){}, true, fd);
}, false);
```

And I get it with my PHP file like so:

```
$new_un = $_POST['jmeno_new'];
$sql_update = ("UPDATE myTable SET `name`='$new_un' WHERE `name`='$name'");
$out = array('type' => 'success_un');
exit(json_encode($out));
```

So if the data is set, I can only see that AJAX request was successful, but it does not change anything in my database.

**What it should do?**

It should update `myTable` where it should replace the old name with the new one, got via `$_POST`.

This does not work.. how? Why?

Comment: Writing a query doesn't mean it will be executed. Please refer to manuals, online tutorials or documentation section here for how to work with database api.

Comment: 1- Validate your else if ($change == 'username') output  var_dump($change) before the else if.

Comment: Don't use interpolation

Comment: the else if works

Comment: 2- Validate the $sql_update value (again var_dump($sql_update))

Comment: `$out = array('type' => 'success_un');` This will pretty much run even if your query fails even after execution. You need to add in a check that you have the right circumstances to send out a success

Comment: Your code is wide open to [SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/275/using-a-database/2685/preventing-sql-injection-with-parametrized-queries)

Comment: Yeah, i know, so else if works, but query does not, WHY ? thats the question ;)

Comment: @Machavity This is just a smaaall part of the code ;)

Comment: Because you __DON'T EXECUTE IT__

Comment: @u_mulder what do you mean by .. I don't execute it? and how to fix that?

Comment: Please see my first comment. That's all.

Comment: @PetrCihlar It means you wrote the query down in code, but you don't do anything with it. Like declaring a variable.

Comment: Also `<input oncut="countChar(this)" onpaste="countChar(this)" onselect="countChar(this)" onfocus="countChar(this)" oninput="countChar(this)" onkeyup="countChar(this)" id="change_username" required name="jmeno_new" type="text" placeholder="New Username">` Attaching event handlers like that into html is just... terrible

Comment: So i need to do something like " ->fetch_assoc()" ?? :)

Comment: @PetrCihlar You need to do something like execute(). It will depend on which database you are using.

Comment: okay, will look at it, thanks for now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you use mysqli:

That's because you don't execute a query. Try to replace this line

```
$sql_update = ("UPDATE myTable SET `name`='$new_un' WHERE `name`='$name'");
```

with this one below:

```
$your_connection_variable->query("UPDATE myTable SET `name`='$new_un' WHERE `name`='$name'");
```

Hope that works! :)

Comment: $sql_update = $mysqli->query ("UPDATE myTable SET `name`='$new_un' WHERE `name`='$name'");

5 minutes ago i rewrited it to this :D LOL

but thanks man ;)